# Firebase iOS Phone Authentication: failure to verify phone number

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do authentication on iOS with Firebase and phone numbers.

The issue I found through the print statements is with SubmitPhoneNumber(). It hits the "we found an error" print statement and the error being reported is

FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER as well as

FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_WEB_CONTEXT_ALREADY_PRESENTED

I am not sure what to make of this or how to go about fixing this. The format for the phone numbers I am passing is "+[country code]1234567890"

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct VerifyPhoneView: View {

    private var phoneNumber: String = ""
    @State private var verificationID: String = ""
    @State private var verificationCode: String = ""
    @State private var loginSuccesful: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var ls: LoginStatus

    init(phoneNumber: String) {
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        submitPhoneNumber()
    }

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Text("My code is")

            TextField("Enter code", text: $verificationCode)

            Button(action: {
                self.submitVerificationCode()
            }) {
                Text("Continue")
            }

        }

    }

    func submitPhoneNumber() {
        print("the submitPhoneNumber method was called")
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+1" + phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("we found an error")
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else {
                print("we did not find an error")
                print(verificationID!)
                self.verificationID = verificationID!
            }
        }
    }

    func submitVerificationCode() {
        print ("222 verificationID is " + self.verificationID)

        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: self.verificationID,
            verificationCode: self.verificationCode)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            print("User signed in succesfully")
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You need to change the calling of submitPhoneNumber()

Comment: @MohitKumar how should I change it?